# Raw-mode is unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, hyper-v, hardware-acceleration, hypervisor

Today I was opening a Virtual Machine on VirtualBox and I can't start it. I had to enable Hyper-V in order to use Android Manager on Android Studio.

Is there any way to run both or do I need to disable Hyper-V?

Thank you all

Comment: This is not a programming question, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features" -> open "Turn Windows feature on or off" -> disable HyperV -> reboot host system

Possible error: "The VM session was aborted". This can be fixed by restarting the virtual machine.